# datepicker not working on IE 8.0

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the jQueryUI-datepicker control to show a calendar in my ASP.NET MVC application.

Using the following code, the date picker pops up fine on FF and Chrome.

```
 $("#Scheduled").datepicker();
```

But on IE 8.0, it doesn't show up at all. Using the Dev tools, here is what I see:

```
<input name="Scheduled" id="Scheduled" type="text" jQuery1335986904515="11" jQuery17109478568619873011="8" value="5/31/2012 12:00:00 PM"/>
```

What am I missing?

EDIT:
I have the following scripts on my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/uploadify/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/uploadify/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/uploadify/swfobject.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/component/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you currently have two versions of jQuery included on the same page? Perhaps jQuery 1.3 and jQuery 1.7.1?

Comment: Just edited the Q above with what I have on my page

Comment: Does it work if you do this instead: `$("#Scheduled").datepicker('show');`

Comment: Can you post a link to the page? Are the Chrome or Firebug consoles showing any errors even though they work?

Comment: OK - this is crazy. For testing I removed the second script tag from my view to see if the popup shows up - it didn't. So I added it back, and everything started working and I now see the popup on IE :O

Comment: Create a blank page and put a datepicker on it. Does it work in IE8 then?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input name="Scheduled" id="Scheduled"  readonly="true"  type="text"/>
```

//in script

```
    $("#Scheduled").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/M/yy', changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
    $("#Scheduled").datepicker("setDate", new Date('31/may/2012'))
```

and change this order also

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/uploadify/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/component/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/uploadify/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.js"></script>  
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/uploadify/swfobject.js"></script>
```